# aws amplify insert data on creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

i have the following question.

I have in my app an Table called `Networkoperator`

This table should be filled on creation. I have an JSON file with the data in it that i need to insert.

How is this achievable?

I was thinking of using an CDK that triggers an lambda only on creation

Answer (score 0):

The Amplify documentation has a [plugins page](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/plugins/plugins/) that lists a bunch of 3rd party plugins. There are two plugins that help seed DB data, but they both appear a bit out of date.

I'd be inclined to make a custom category (`amplify add custom`) and make it a dependency of the database table (ideally created and managed by Amplify). Then you can do anything you like in the 'build' step of the custom category's `package.json`. The [aws-cdk-dynamodb-seeder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cdk-dynamodb-seeder) package looks like it would do the trick (but was also published 2 years ago). Within the custom category, you can pull in the DB table name, etc, to avoid hardcoding.